# node.js global variable between different functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, session-variables

I'm using Nodejs, Express and MongoDB for creating a web application.
For the user registration I assign an ID to each user using a function called by the action (POST) of a form and I assign also a confirmation code (like "123456") for checking the identity of the user into another function called by the confirmation page that appear after the registration page.
How can I get the user ID into the other function? (called after pressing submit into another form)

Do I have to use sessions? I think I don't know the right approach to these things

edit: I store the user data into a mongoDB database

Comment: If you have two different requests, and you'd like to persist data between them, you have to use a DB, and you're already using a DB, so just store, and then get, should be straight forward ?

Comment: yes, the problem is I have to remember the ID of the user for checking his verification code

Comment: you don't need a DB, that's a PHP-style solution. just define an object outside the request function and all responses can set and get its values. Pulling a key from RAM is going to be orders of magnitude faster than using any sort of a DB, and is the main advantage node.js has over run-once languages that NEED a db to store info between executions. In general, if you're pulling db SELECTs that only return one row, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: @dandavis I whole heartedly disagree with in memory stores in production like you are suggesting. 1) Globals are evil and not dependable — we all know that 2) Memory will be localized to the process and therefore you can only scale vertically, not horizontally, which is one of the TRUE beauties of node. 3) What happens when the process goes down? All users will be logged out? A `redis` store is much more fault tolerant and robust then a global and will help you scale horizontally when ready.

Comment: Initializing a DB or redis call uses a lot more ram than a single string property. i don't think "123456" has a very big footprint. nobody said it has to be a global, it has to be common. Additionally, one can delete the key/value as soon as the confirmation page is printed. If you have so many users between those 2 pages that you're running out of RAM storing string IDs, you've surely already ran out of RAM anyway. KISS

Comment: @dandavis You missed the point. Its not HOW MUCH memory the solution uses, but HOW it uses that memory. Quite simply, you're solution will not scale outside a single process and therefore is not a production quality solution. I would certainly do that in development to KISS, but NEVER would you see an enterprise solution scoped to a single process. My guess is you don't maintain a production node stack.

Comment: the OP's mention of sessions implies that the two requests will be served by the same box, at least with loadbalancers i've seen... When node can handle 10,000 users at once on a single thread, it would take a lot of user signups to cause issue. While i like redis and agree with the spirit of your concerns, in this particular instance I see no hint of such scale or justification for premature optimization. If we were talking about the main app routine or uploaded files, i'd be inclined to agree with you. Since were talking about a tiny bit of temp data, i don't believe it will be a problem...

Comment: @dandavis Again, you don't maintain a node stack so you probably shouldn't be suggesting things "theoretically" or what you heard in a blog post/white papers on node. You are quite simply wrong here. Which is ok, its how we learn

Comment: Tend to agree with @jibsales - on this. The way Node is set up you certainly can use a variable to hold some data between requests, but that's just bad practice, not only in Node, but in javascript and just about any language in general. It's not very reliant to use variables for this, and suddenly someone decides to try out clusters or a multitude of other things that Node support that would lead to a miserable failure. The way to go is to use a database for this, not matter how tiny the piece of data you're going to store is.

Comment: As a sidenote, if you're using Express sessions are built in and can easily be hooked up to any database.

Comment: @adeneo And it even uses an in memory store for development, if thats you're thing ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say you're thinking the right way, and just need a short guide to get to do it. Sessions are the way to go here, and although you could store those anywhere, I'd suggest you start with basic in-memory sessions for now.

I found the following guide helpful: http://blog.modulus.io/nodejs-and-express-sessions. Just take it as far as Redis and not further, and you'll be well on your way.